# Touch Bar API availability

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, nstouchbar

When will the new Touch Bar functionality be available for use, and will it be available for both Swift and Objective-C? For which macOS version will it be available?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/macos/touch-bar/ seems to be a good starting point: Reference, sample code, guidelines, ...

Comment: Swift and ObjectiveC are just programming languages. The API for adding support to your MacOS app to use this new hardware feature should be accessible from either language. Likely Mac OS Sierra will have support and so will Xcode 8.1.

Comment: **This is not a general computing question** and should not be closed as such.

Answer (score 4):

1. Xcode 8.1 supports Touch Bar for Macs that include it, and supports adding Touch Bar functionality to your app. [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html).
2. Will be available for both Swift and Objective-C
3. Available for **macOS 10.12.1+**

Read more on [NSTouchBar](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstouchbar?language=objc) from Apple.

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple Developer's documentation:

> To develop apps that use the Touch Bar, your Mac will need to run Xcode 8.1 on macOS Sierra 10.12.1 (16B2657) or later.

---

There are two builds for macOS Sierra 10.12.1:

> [image: Image 1]

However, Touch Bar specifically requires Build 16B2657, Build 16B2555 doesn't work.